# Inbound service from Twilio configured in Softphone Layout not able to create a case in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, twilio

I have configured a Twilio Flex connected app within Salesforce for Call, SMS, SSO, and Facebook services. All the services mentioned are working fine. Basically, the idea is to create a case for an inbound service like call/SMS, etc. For that, I have configured a Softphone layout that is used for handling these inbound services inside Salesforce (Please have a look at the screenshot provided below) and creating a case with the help of the "Create a Case". But, it is giving an error as attached in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There's no screenshots whatsoever

Comment: I have fixed the screenshot, maybe you don't want to share your phone number that is visible in it thought. The question seems a little unclear still.